# can i use java library(Swiss Ephemeris) in xcode project for ios developmenat?

Tags: java, swift, xcode

I am building an IOS app in which i want to use **Swiss Ephemeris** library which is a jar file. But i am new in Xcode and swift both . My concern is how i can use jar file in my Xcode project for IOS development.
I downloaded jar file from the http://www.th-mack.de/international/download/
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a JAR file is a Java Archive which means you need to have Java installed on the system you want to use it (You cannot open or use a jar file on Windows or on macOS, unless you have Java installed). Same goes for iOS. For using a jar file in your app, iOS needs to have Java installed which it doesn't. And if it did, you couldn't even access the library functions because it's Java and not Swift.

Answer (score 0):

The library is written in a different language than the app. While in some cases, such as C++ code being able to run on iOS, java isn't able to.

This is because Java runs inside of the JVM (Java virtual machine). It runs the compiled java byte code. However, iOS doesn't have the JVM on it at all, so the iPhone in question wouldn't be able to understand at all what this "jar" file is.

For that reason, you will not be able to use this library - or for that matter, any Java library while writing an iOS app.